# The charts of $\Bbb{P^1(C})$ are defined over $\Bbb{Q}$. Those of $y^2=x^3+5x+1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Say that the complex manifolds $X=\Bbb{P^1(C)}$ and $X=\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)}$ are defined over $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$ respectively, because there are finitely many charts $\phi_j:U_j\to X$ such that $\phi_l^{-1}\circ \phi_j$ sends $K\cap U_j\to K\cap U_l$ *(if $K\subset \Bbb{R}$ then $\Bbb{R}\cap U_j$ must be non-empty)*

The (projective) elliptic curve $E:zy^2=x^3+5xz^2+z^3$ (without complex multiplication), which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z)}$ for some probably transcendental number $\tau$, has some charts defined over two kind of fields:

- $\Bbb{Q}(\tau)$
- The infinite algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining iteratively $a^{1/2}$ and $f^{-1}(a^2)$ for each $a$ in that field, where $f(T)=T^3+5T+1$.

It raises a few questions, for example

> Are there other kind of fields defining $E$ ? Which compact complex manifolds are defined over a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ ? Over an extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ finitely generated as a field ?

Comment: I don't know why your question is being downvoted--it's a legitimate question. It seems as though your notion of 'defined' is a bit ill-defined though. Namely, you seem to be assuming that you can talk about a notion of 'rational points' inside of $X$ (for which the charts respect), but you actually can't talk aboug rational points without defining a model first! Are you comfortable with algebraic geometry language so that saying that $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ means that there is some $X_0$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $X=(X_0)_{\mathbb{C}}$? Also, do you really mean compact

Comment: complex manifold, or do you mean complex algebraic variety? If it's the former then it's not clear what you really mean, if it's the latter then you can make this precise in the way I intimated above. In that case, every variety over any characteristic field is defined over a finitely generated extension of $\mathbb{Q}$--take equations defining your variety and adjoin them to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For just elliptic curves though, I should mention that the minimal field of definability of a curve over $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(j(E))$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Once some charts are given, $K\cap U_j$ is a subset of $\Bbb{C}$, then we can try every possible charts for our **complex manifold** to check which subfield $K$ of $\Bbb{C}$ works. For 1-dimensional manifolds I guess it is most mostly the Möbius transformations which give finitely generated fields. I was wondering about the modularity theorem but the chart at $i\infty$ for the modular curves is built from $q\to \frac{\log q}{2i\pi}$ so it shouldn't give an interesting $K$.